# Get Hidden Field of HTML using Kanna, Swift, and AlamoFire

Tags: html, swift, alamofire

I am using Swift, Kanna Library, and Alamofire to try to retrieve any of these html hidden field values below

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="empl_id" id="empl_id" value="M12345">
    <input type="hidden" name="current_fac_id" id="current_fac_id" value="12345">
    <input type="hidden" name="empl_role" id="empl_role" value="supervisor">
</form>
```

I am able to retrieve a regular div, h2, h3 just fine.  But I can seem to grab the hidden.

Here what I tried below

```
func parseHtmlField(html: String) -> Void {
        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            for words in doc.css("input[id^='empl_id']") {
                                    print(words["value"]!)
            }
        }
}
```

I specifically need the values of the input fields.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I was able to return the ids of the form elements using "print(words["id"]! as String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is the correct syntax for the problem.  The hidden problem I did not foresee was the swift code extracting the value, before the html page JavaScript assigned a value to that specific element in the page.